# JSF Composite that component that outputs ONLY a facet

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, facet

I've been trying to create a composite component that outputs a facet.

header.xhtml

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="headerLabel"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <f:facet name="header">
    #{cc.attrs.headerLabel}
  </f:facet>
</composite:implementation>
```

I want to be able to do something of the sort:

```
<p:datatable>
  <app:header headerLabel="This is a test"/>
</p:datatable>
```

But nothing gets rendered. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Never tried this (odd requirement), but a tag file should theoretically work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6822000

Answer (score 0):

Following on what @BalusC said (a million thanks!), using tag file worked. This was more than enough:

```
<ui:composition ...>
  <f:facet name="header">
    #{headerLabel}
  </f:facet>
  ...
</ui:composition>
```